# Passing std::forward as a default argument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, function-pointers, forward

Consider the following function that takes a function as argument.

```
template <class Function = std::plus<int> > 
void apply(Function&& f = Function());
```

Here `std::plus<int>` is the default function that is applied. `std::plus<int>` is a function object and all works well.

Now, I would like to pass `std::forward<int>` as the default argument. `std::forward<int>` is not a function object, this is a function pointer. How to do that ?

```
template <class Function = /* SOMETHING */ > 
void apply(Function&& f = /* SOMETHING */);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of a function pointer to `std::forward<int>` is `int &&(*)(int &)`. So your function would look like this:

```
template<class T = int &&(*)(int &)>
void apply(T &&t = &std::forward<int>);
```

Take a look at how std::forward is declared: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward

Answer (score 2):

I think this will work:

```
template <class Function = decltype(&std::forward<int>)> 
void apply(Function&& f = &std::forward<int>);
```

Edit: actually, maybe not. You're better off just overloading it:

```
void apply() {
  apply(&std::forward);
}
```